# select data from mysql with mysql-connector-python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a mysql db that I manage via MAMP (using port 3306, server is on port 80). I have downloaded and installed the mysql-connector-python library from Oracle and am trying to access and manipulate the db.  Curiously, following the tutorials at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-tutorial-cursorbuffered.html, I'm able to run a query to insert new records into a specific table (as long as I issue the .commit() method on my connector).

However, I can't seem to retrieve any data with a simple select command.  So the query, "Select * from `Assignments`" returns None.

```
query = ('''SELECT title,description FROM  `Assignments` LIMIT 0 , 30''')

cursor = cnx.cursor()
result = cursor.execute(query)
print "result:",result

#All assignment info
for (title, description) in results:
    print title, description
```

I keep getting the error, "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable".  I believe this has to do with the fact that the result of the executed query is None.  B/c I'm able to commit update and insert changes to the db, I know that I'm connecting just fine.  Why can't I run a simple SELECT command and get something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a [`MySQLCursor.fetchall`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html) method to get the results .

```
cursor.execute(query)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

or

```
cursor.execute(query)
head_rows = cursor.fetchmany(size=2)
remaining_rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Thank you @Alexander!  This worked beautifully.  I wonder why it's not mentioned on the documentation tutorial page (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html).  What's there is what results in the error (for me).

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to call *fetchall*, if you look at the docs you will see there is no assignment to the return value of the execute call as the method returns *None*, you just *execute* and then iterate over the [MySQLCursor/cursor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor.html) object:

```
query = ('''SELECT title,description FROM  `Assignments` LIMIT 0 , 30''')

cursor = cnx.cursor()

# forget assigning, just execute
cursor.execute(query)

# iterate over the cursor 
for (title, description) in cursor:
    print title, description
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `mycursor.fetchone()` then do the following:

```
   myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
   row_count = mycursor.rowcount
    
   if row_count == 1:
      row_id = myresult[0]
      print(row_id)
```

Basically you can access the `items as an array like myresult[0], myresult[1]` and so on....